# Как ассоциировать свой протокол в windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, protocol

Допустим я хочу реализовать поддержку своего протокола `foo`, так что бы при открытии ресурса `foo://blablabla` в браузере, вызывалась моя программа `foo.exe` с аргументом `foo://blablabla`. Данная поддержка должна работать для windows 7,8,10.
Для windows 7 это делается довольно просто - просто добавляется запись в реестр вида:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
myscheme
(Default) = "URL:Foo Protocol"
URL Protocol = ""
DefaultIcon
   (Default) = "foo.exe,1"
shell
   open
      command
           (Default) = "C:\Program Files\Foo\foo.exe" "%1"
```

Но! Страница с этим API (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/aa767914) уже помечена как устаревшая (рекомендуемая версия ведет условно говоря в никуда - ну по крайней мере по рекомендуемой ссылке я ничего не нашел). Насколько понимаю, таким способом нельзя пользоваться под более новыми версиями (он кстати работает под windows 10 - почему, не знаю). Начал изучать этот вопрос для windows 8 (https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/w8cookbook/file-type-and-protocol-associations-model) и там написано что теперь программы не могут корректно сами уставливать свои ассоциации - но как такое возможно? ведь пример выше работает у меня.

Вот цитата из документации

> The file type and URI association model has changed in Windows 8. Apps are no longer able to programmatically set themselves as the default handler for a file type or URI. Instead, now the user always controls what the default handler is for a file type or URI scheme.

Насколько я понимаю, и windows 10 тоже не должна поддерживать такую установку ассоциаций? Как можно реализовать поддержку этих протоколов под этими тремя версиями windows? честно говоря, из документации я вообще ничего не понял. Только смутно представляю, что теперь пользователь сам должен управлять этими ассоциациями? Вот небольшая выдержка для windows 8

> Do integrate with the Set Default Programs control panel if you want to allow users of your app to access the default management UI (the management UI within the app is no longer supported)
>
> Calling IApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI::LaunchAdvancedAssociationUI allows the user to access the ‘Set Default Programs’ control panel page for the specified app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще-то там написано немного не о том. Программы по-прежнему могут устанавливать свои ассоциации, нельзя только принудительно делать их ассоциациями по умолчанию. Это теперь может делать только пользователь, и это правильно.

Если ваша программа единственная с этой ассоциацией, никаких проблем быть не должно. Если какая-то другая программа тоже ассоциирует себя с такими файлами, то пользователь сам выберет, какой программой он хочет эти файлы открывать.

Comment: А где это вы нашли? Я статью на английском тяжело осилил. То есть я могу точно также как раньше определять ассоциации и будет работать? Тогда почему признали апи устаревшим?

Comment: @LmTinyToon, как где? Да по вашей же ссылке. :) Да, можете как раньше определять ассоциации, и все будет работать. Во всяком случае, у меня работает без проблем. Я сам никогда не лез в умолчания, так что об изменениях узнал из вашего вопроса. Озадачился вопросу, почитал по вашим ссылкам, а потом еще и проверил под Win10. Проблемы нет.

Comment: @LmTinyToon, что же касается вопроса "_почему признали апи устаревшим_", я не заметил там упоминаний, что оно устаревшее. Но надо заметить, что обработка URI завязана на браузер, а IE уже не актуален. Это надо по конкретным браузерам смотреть кто такой протокол поддерживает, а кто нет.

Comment: я удивился, но этот способ работает для всех браузеров (просто проверил, их документацию не смотрел)